# I can't run my sigmoid function code in python by visual studio

Tags: python, python-3.x, sigmoid

I try to make a simple sigmoid function in visual studio by python but this can't run the value.

```
import math
def basic_sigmoid(x) :
    """
    Compute sigmoid of x.

    Arguments :
    x -- A Scalar

    Return :
    s --- sigmoid(x) 
    """

    s = 1/(1+math.exp(-x))

    return s
basic_sigmoid(3)
```

Comment: Works just fine. What is the exact problem (or an error message)?

Comment: @kmayutrisna do you want to print(s), so that you can see the value of sigmoid?

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine, and I think your problem is nothing shown on the console after running the python file. Unlike interactive python tools like Ipython, you need to print this result.

```
import math
def basic_sigmoid(x) :
    """
    Compute sigmoid of x.

    Arguments :
    x -- A Scalar

    Return :
    s --- sigmoid(x) 
    """

    s = 1/(1+math.exp(-x))

    return s
print(basic_sigmoid(3))
```